# Awsomeness magic job screening - how do I avoid failing the test?

Tags: magic, alternate-reality

[Related to a previous question of mine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123896/awesomeness-powered-magic-why-would-a-group-of-awesome-magicians-want-to-keep)

The time want by, the technology advanced, dave (still with a lower case D) became noting more then a story told to kids before bed, but despite it all the power of awesomeness magic remained to our modern day.

In the story a gang of robbers needs an inside man, luckily their target HQ has a job opening that will allow one of them to become that insider, the only problem is that awesomeness in this world is easily testable, a potential employer can just ask a candidate to make the biggest fireball possible & as the size of the fireball is directly related to the person awesomeness he will immediately know if his awesome or not.

It's common for companies to ask you to make a light-ball while the interview goes on, lie (which is not awesome) and the light intensity goes down (similar to RL lie detection test only cheap and without the hassle so it's a lot more common).

**Now being a bad guy the selected thief is of course not as awesome as hard working men & women so how do I make our thief pass the magic lie detection test & still get the job?**

**Assumptions:**

- Aside from that the thief is qualified enough to pass all the other "normal" tests for the job and will be the one picked of all candidates if he can just pass this magical job screening issue.
- The job in question is in a field where this kinds of lie detection tests are mandatory due to regulatory reasons (and yes the politicians who decided about that aren't awesome but politicians are never awesome).
- There is no way to fake awesomeness, that would not be awesome.
- Other then awesome magic being common the world is pretty much like our own.

Comment: Is something wrong with old-fashioned bribery with an awesome flair?

Comment: bribery assumes a dishonest interviewer, trickery doesn't rely on lucking out on having a corrupt one conducting the interview (besides it will make for a less interesting story).

Comment: If you are assuming an honest interviewer, consider adding it to the assumptions.

Comment: He might be honest, he might not, the point is that the thieves can't rely on it so even if he does turn out to be willing to take a bribe they (being famous expert thieves) will surly have a backup plan in case he's an honest interviewer.

Answer (score 3):

This job will require two candidates, each with enough awesomeness to create some kind of light ball.  The less-awesome of the two candidates goes in first with no preparation and of course fails.  But leaving the interview, he bring back several key pieces of information; most notably the make and model of the photography photometer/light-meter which the interviewer uses to measure candidate light ball intensity, and the appearance and style of any sun glasses the interviewer may put on during the test.

The second candidate is not only more awesome than her partner, she is also a skilled pick pocket.  Just prior to the beginning of her interview, she bumps into the interviewer (perhaps flirtatiously) and switches his light meter with an exact duplicate which has been doctored to give false readings when instructed by a remote control in her shoe.  She is also wearing a broach which on toe-command can emit brilliant uv light, which is strong enough to make the interviewer's eyes ache and tuned to penetrate his preferred sunglasses but otherwise invisible to human vision.

With these tools in place, she is ready to ace the interview and become your inside "man".

Comment: That's a great idea for small changes in brightness but what to do if said changes are large enough to be visible to the naked eye?

Comment: That is why she wears the UV broach.  So she can make the interviewer's eyes water from the moment her meager light ball appears.  Through tears and while ineffectively shading/shielding his eyes, the interviewer will have no line-of-sight perception of the ball's brightness and will therefore have to trust what his light meter is telling him.

Comment: I quite like this idea... simple & effective.

Answer (score 2):

## The thief is awesome

Awesome is a quite subjective word, a super hero might be awesome, a volunteer man who goes to work every day even when is raining, storming, snowing or whatever condition its determination is also awesome. A thief who infiltrates on big organizations tricks the security and steal a bank as a spy is also awesome. Awesomeness is justified.

Your thief can perfectly lie to the interviewer. Instead of thinking as lying, you could think it as infiltrating, evading enemy psychological defenses, tricking the organization security or cheating the interviewer insight about you. A secret agent is also awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The real insider is just an awesome spy. Secret agents may be bad at lying, but they have awesome style for miles. But see, **the awesome spy isn't even in on it**. They think they're infiltrating the front corporation of an insidious organized crime syndicate. The real thieves act as secret agent handlers, delivering orders. How are they able to do it? The spy is actually just barely awesome enough for the job, and for their presumed mission. But they think they're way awesomer than that, which is kinda not so awesome. The thieves however are really nasty un-awesome, way more than the spy is awesome. Naturally this means they are amazing liars, and silly hijinks ensue.

Answer (score 2):

## I just forgot my evil plan! I think it's Awesome!

One of the other robbers, who is Awesome, uses awesome magic to make the spy forget that he has any evil plans to become an insider. Then, when he's asked about it, he doesn't have to lie. His awesomeness is maintained, and he becomes the insider. After the interview, the magic wears off, then he realizes that he lied and then he's less awesome, but no one is looking at him when he finds out, and he's not making a ball of light anymore.

Comment: "Hey, it really was me who stole my dad's keys"

Answer (score 1):

Blackmail or threaten to put the pet cat/Wife/record collection of someone who is really awesome into a wood chipper, unless they take the job and help the thieves with the heist.